# Modifying the ATU reports descriptions when listeners are used in testng.xml

Tags: selenium-webdriver, report, testng

I have the following lines in my testng.xml

```
 <listeners>
  <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener"></listener>
  <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ConfigurationListener"></listener>
  <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.MethodListener"></listener>
  </listeners>
```

The issue here is that the ATU reports are generated with the default names for Report Description, Run Description. On researching, I found that we can change these by making modifications in the atu.properties file. However, as I am using the listeners in testng.xml directly, I am not referencing the properties file.

So the question - Is there any way of modifying the descriptions using the listeners as I am doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid null pointer exception you can use below code snippet.

**ATUReports.setWebDriver(driver);
ATUReports.setAuthorInfo("User Name", Utils.getCurrentTime(),"1.0");**

From http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.in/2013/12/ATUReporterPart2.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify the ATU properties with:

```
System.setProperty("atu.reporter.config", "Path of properties file");
```

You can set this configuration in your own [`IExecutionListener`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IExecutionListener.html).

From http://www.testingdiaries.com/testng-reports-atu-reporter/

Comment: The above code needs to be added in every class that I am planning to run. To avoid this, I am trying to find out if we can mention something in the testng.xml so that modification once would apply to the entire suite.

Comment: Just implement a http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IExecutionListener.html and register it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, in the method, if I try to set the author name, version etc., a null pointer error is got. Have you faced a similar issue?

Comment: I've never used ATU. But you can ask another question with the full stacktrace. (don't forget to validate my answer if your question is closed)